# Subfigures placed horizontally

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I want to place two or more figures on top of the two-column page next to each other (horizontally). However, for some reason I can't do this. This is the code that I use, it puts the second figure in the new line. Why is that? Btw, figures are tiny and many of them can fit in one line.

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering

\subfigure[Market revenue]{
{\epsfig{file = figures/graphs/revenue.pdf, width = 3cm}}
\label{fig:evaluation:revenue}
}

\subfigure[Average price]{
{\epsfig{file = figures/graphs/avgPrice.pdf, width = 3cm}}
\label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}
}

\caption{Simulation results}
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use an empty line between the two subfigures:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering

\subfigure[Market revenue]{%
{\epsfig{file = figures/graphs/revenue.pdf, width = 3cm}}%
\label{fig:evaluation:revenue}%
}\qquad
\subfigure[Average price]{%
{\epsfig{file = figures/graphs/avgPrice.pdf, width = 3cm}}%
\label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}%
}

\caption{Simulation results}
\end{figure*}
```

However you should be using the package **subfig** instead of the obsolete **subfigure** and **graphicx** with its more powerful commands instead of **epsfig** (which should never be used in new documents, it exists only for compatibility with older ones).

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering

\subfloat[Market revenue]{%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{figures/graphs/revenue}%
  \label{fig:evaluation:revenue}%
}\qquad
\subfloat[Average price]{%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{figures/graphs/avgPrice}%
  \label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}%
}

\caption{Simulation results}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: What package are these examples? It doesn't compile with graphicx and subfig for me.

Answer (score 5):

Update to answer from: @egreg

1. Empty line did cause problem for me as well. Took off the empty line my images went horizontally. There are a few symbols to add space between subfigures: **~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill**. (Update from @Werner: a few more symbols to control horizontal space explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/5764).)
2. According to this [latex page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) on wikibooks.org, **subfig** is also deprecated now, and the recommended package is **subcaption**:

> A useful extension is the subcaption package which uses subfloats within a single float. The subfigure and subfig packages are deprecated however they are useful alternatives when used in-conjunction with latex templates (i.e templates for journals from Springer and IOP, IEEETran and ACM SIG) that are not compatible with subcaption. These packages give the author the ability to have subfigures within figures, or subtables within table floats.

Comment: [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) is not marked as *obsolete* on CTAN...

Comment: ...there are far more [horizontal spacing commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/5764) than you mention.