# What commands are there for horizontal spacing?

Tags: spacing

I know that `\:` in LaTeX produces a space when rendered.

Are there any alternatives, because my LaTeX renderer doesn't support `\:` (it renders it as text), and there is no help / FAQ that I can find.

Comment: `\bigskip` skips a line. Just leaving this here for me :)

Answer (score 1375, accepted):

There are a number of horizontal spacing macros for LaTeX:

1. `\,` inserts a `.16667em` space in text mode, or `\thinmuskip` (equivalent to `3mu`) in math mode; there's an equivalent `\thinspace` macro;
2. `\!` is the *negative* equivalent to `\,`; there's an equivalent `\negthinspace` macro;
3. `\>` (or `\:`) inserts a `.2222em` space in text mode, or `\medmuskip` (equivalent to `4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu`) in math mode; there's an equivalent `\medspace`;
4. `\negmedspace` is the *negative* equivalent to `\medspace`;
5. `\;` inserts a `.2777em` space in text mode, or `\thickmuskip` (equivalent to `5.0mu plus 5.0mu`) in math mode; there's an equivalent `\thickspace`;
6. `\negthickspace` is the *negative* equivalent to `\thickspace`;
7. `\enspace` inserts a space of `.5em` in text or math mode;
8. `\quad` inserts a space of `1em` in text or math mode;
9. `\qquad` inserts a space of `2em` in text or math mode;
10. `\kern <len>` inserts a skip of `<len>` (may be negative) in text or math mode (a plain TeX skip); there's also a `m`ath-specific `\mkern <math len>`;
11. `\hskip <len>` (similar to `\kern`);
12. `\hspace{<len>}` inserts a space of length `<len>` (may be negative) in math or text mode (a LaTeX `\hskip`);
13. `\hphantom{<stuff>}` inserts space of length equivalent to `<stuff>` in math or text mode. `\phantom{<stuff>}` is similar, inserting a horizontal and vertical space that matches `<stuff>`. Should be `\protect`ed when used in fragile commands (like `\caption` and sectional headings);
14. `\`  inserts what is called a "control space" (in text or math mode);
15. inserts an inter-word space in text mode (and is gobbled in math mode). Similarly for `\space` and `{ }`.
16. `~` inserts an "unbreakable" space (similar to an HTML `&nbsp;`) (in text or math mode);
17. `\hfill` inserts a so-called "rubber length" or stretch between elements (in text or math mode). Note that you may need to provide a type of anchor to fill from/to; see [What is the difference between `\hspace*{\fill}` and `\hfill`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45948/5764);

Your usage *should* work in *math mode*, so try `$\:$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

There are a number of horizontal spacing macros for LaTeX:

\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
  \verb|a\,b|                     & a\,b \quad $a\, b$ \\
  \verb|a\thinspace b|            & a\thinspace b \quad $a\thinspace b$ \\
  \verb|a\!b|                     & a\!b \quad $a\!b$ \\
  \verb|a\negthinspace b|         & a\negthinspace b \quad $a\negthinspace b$ \\
  \verb|a\:b|                     & a\:b \quad $a\:b$ \\
  \verb|a\>b|                     & a\>b \quad $a\>b$ \\
  \verb|a\medspace b|             & a\medspace b \quad $a\medspace b$ \\
  \verb|a\negmedspace b|          & a\negmedspace b \quad $a\negmedspace b$ \\
  \verb|a\;b|                     & a\;b \quad $a\;b$ \\
  \verb|a\thickspace b|           & a\thickspace b \quad $a\thickspace b$ \\
  \verb|a\negthickspace b|        & a\negthickspace b \quad $a\negthickspace b$ \\
  \verb|$a\mkern\thinmuskip b$|   & $a\mkern\thinmuskip b$ (similar to \verb|\,|) \\
  \verb|$a\mkern-\thinmuskip b$|  & $a\mkern-\thinmuskip b$ (similar to \verb|\!|) \\
  \verb|$a\mkern\medmuskip b$|    & $a\mkern\medmuskip b$ (similar to \verb|\:| or \verb|\>|) \\
  \verb|$a\mkern-\medmuskip b$|   & $a\mkern-\medmuskip b$ (similar to \verb|\negmedspace|) \\
  \verb|$a\mkern\thickmuskip b$|  & $a\mkern\thickmuskip b$ (similar to \verb|\;|) \\
  \verb|$a\mkern-\thickmuskip b$| & $a\mkern-\thickmuskip b$ (similar to \verb|\negthickspace|) \\
  \verb|a\enspace b|              & a\enspace b \\
  \verb|$a\enspace b$|            & $a\enspace b$ \\
  \verb|a\quad b|                 & a\quad b \\
  \verb|$a\quad b$|               & $a\quad b$ \\
  \verb|a\qquad b|                & a\qquad b \\
  \verb|$a\qquad b$|              & $a\qquad b$ \\
  \verb|a\hskip 1em b|            & a\hskip 1em b \\
  \verb|$a\hskip 1em b$|          & $a\hskip 1em b$ \\
  \verb|a\kern 1pc b|             & a\kern 1pc b \\
  \verb|$a\kern 1pc b$|           & $a\kern 1pc b$ \\
  \verb|$a\mkern 17mu b$|         & $a\mkern 17mu b$ \\
  \verb|a\hspace{35pt}b|          & a\hspace{35pt}b \\
  \verb|$a\hspace{35pt}b$|        & $a\hspace{35pt}b$ \\
  \verb|axyzb|                    & axyzb \\
  \verb|a\hphantom{xyz}b|         & a\hphantom{xyz}b (or just \verb|\phantom|) \\
  \verb|$axyzb$|                  & $axyzb$ \\
  \verb|$a\hphantom{xyz}b$|       & $a\hphantom{xyz}b$ (or just \verb|\phantom|) \\
  \verb|a b|                      & a b \\
  \verb|$a b$|                    & $a b$ \\
  \verb|a\space b|                & a\space b \\
  \verb|$a\space b$|              & $a\space b$ \\
  \verb|a\ b|                     & a\ b \\
  \verb|$a\ b$|                   & $a\ b$ \\
  \verb|a{ }b|                    & a{ }b \\
  \verb|$a{ }b$|                  & $a{ }b$ \\
  \verb|a~b|                      & a~b \\
  \verb|$a~b$|                    & $a~b$ \\
  \verb|a\hfill b|                & a\hfill b \\
  \verb|$a\hfill b$|              & $a\hfill b$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner -- `\ ` (backslash space) inserts a space equivalent to a word space; would be usefully added.  also, in `tabbing`, `\>` will "add space" as a function of skipping to the next "tab stop"; adding this information may or may not be useful.

Comment: How about italics correction, with `\/`?

Comment: Don't forget `\kern` and `\mkern` for text and math modes, respectively, when you wish to prevent the inadvertent addition of glue.

Comment: I just noticed that `\hfil` has already been suggested but it hasn't been included in your table. It's worthy to mention the construct `a\hfill\hfill b\hfill c` and the similar use of `\hfil` -- `a\hfil\hfil b\hfil c`

Comment: Also `\space` is missing from the list.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Just added `\space`, ' ' and `{ }`.

Comment: Note that most of the `<len>`'s are actually glue expressions.

Comment: @Werner I thought you might like to add `\mspace` as a LaTeX command with can deal the unit `mu`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400680/unit-mu-unknown?noredirect=1#comment997528_400680

Comment: In the description of `\>`, does "4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu" mean 2.0mu?  If, so why not just say that?  On the other hand, in the compiled output above, it looks like `\>` inserts exactly the same amount of space as `\;`, and I'm reading the description of `\;` as implying that it inserts 10.0mu.  Is `mu` not a unit of length?  (Hmm.  Maybe relativistic effects.  Some of those sequences must be moving more quickly than others....  :-)

Comment: @Mars: `mu` is a `m`ath `u`nit, and varies in length depending on the style you're in (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, or `\scriptscriptstyle`), similar to how `em` and `ex` varies within text mode based on the active font. Also, `x plus y minus z` refer to "rubber lengths" that can stretch from `x` to `x+y` or shrink to `x-z`, as needed, based on the surrounding text within the paragraph. If used within a box, or fully-stretchable environment (like a `tabular`'s `l`, `c` or `r` columns), it'll result in a spacing of `x`, since there is no need to stretch or shrink.

Comment: Thanks Werner.  That's helpful.  I would suggest adding that kind of explanation to the answer, but having it in this comment is good enough.

Comment: Very simplistic but effective answer!

Comment: why only fixed, how to custom cm etc

Comment: @ItsmeJulian: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "custom cm, etc.".

Comment: @Werner Do you have a similar answer for the vertical spaces? Pleas add similar answer for the vertical spaces as well.

Comment: Also, `\llap` and `\rlap` have a "no-space" effect (a bit OT maybe? :)

Comment: `\,` is non-breaking space too.

Comment: @Werner You can update a little bit your _super response_ including the changes of the LaTeX October 2020?

Comment: @Werner Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. It might help others to know that compilation with `pdflatex` (v3.14159265) and `lualatex` (v1.12.0), both from TeX Live 2020/Debian, seem to require a few changes:
 1. load the package `amsmath` (defines `\!`, `\:`, `\>`, `\medspace`, `\negmedspace`, `\;`, `\thickspace`, and `\negthickspace`);
 2. change the line `\verb|a\>b| & a\>b \quad $a\>b$ \\` to `\verb|$a\>b$| & $a\>b$ \\` (`\>` seems to be defined in math-mode only).

Comment: +1: I now realize that half of your reputation comes from this answer alone :).

Comment: that is the definite answer.  I like it!

Comment: Will these work in \begin{gathered} .....

Comment: @user3582228: Some work in math mode, some don't.

Comment: perhaps this answer should mention that `\kern` produces vertical space when in vertical mode (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/90645), so it's not exactly a horizontal spacing command (if I understand it correctly)