# Phantom malfunction in algorithm caption

Tags: captions, algorithms

I am trying to use `\phantom` in the context of an algorithm caption. I am using the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages. `\phantom` will work properly in normal text in my document, but not in a caption. Is there a workaround to get whitespace into a caption? I have tried things like `\hbox` and using `\includegraphics[width=0.25in]{smallWhiteImage.png}` to create some space. None of these have worked yet.

Any help would be great! Please see the code example below.

What I have:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ TestAlgorithm \newline
\textbf{SomeInputs} input1, \newline $\cdots$ input2, input3, input4, \newline $\cdots$ input5, input6, input7 \newline
\textbf{AnOutput} output1 }
\label{algo:TestAlgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $oh yeah!$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

What I want:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ TestAlgorithm \newline
\textbf{SomeInputs} input1, \newline \phantom{$\cdots$} input2, input3, input4, \newline \phantom{$\cdots$} input5, input6, input7 \newline
\textbf{AnOutput} output1 }
\label{algo:TestAlgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $oh yeah!$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).   While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Try using `\protect\phantom{$\cdots$}`.

Comment: Very cool! That works perfectly. Thank you for the very prompt response, I appreciate it!

Comment: Why do you want to place the inputs and outputs in the caption? If you are interested only in some rules, there are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Consider `\hspace*{2em}` or similar for getting a non disappearing space at the beginning of a line.

Comment: For general spacing techniques (horizontally), see [Any alternatives for whitespace other than `\:` in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\protect\phantom{$\cdots$}` to be able to use a `\phantom` as desired:

[image]

As per egreg's comments you can also use `\hspace*{2em}` to specify much space you want to add.  You can specify an absolute horizontal space as in `\hspace*{1.0cm}`, but it is better to use measurements that adjust based on the current font -- `1em` is approximately the horizontal width on the letter `m`.  Other useful horizontal spaces you can use include:

[image]

There is also a negative thin space, `\!` which is useful in certain situations.

### Notes:

- If you need more info on horizontal spacing refer to [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing).
- If you really need exactly the space used by `$cdots$`, you can use `\settowidth` to measure that size for you:

  ```
    \newlength{\WidthOfCdots}\settowidth{\WidthOfCdots}{$\cdots$}
  ```

  and then using

  ```
     \hspace*{\WidthOfCdots}
  ```

  will produce exactly the desired horizontal space.

### Code:

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newlength{\WidthOfCdots}\settowidth{\WidthOfCdots}{$\cdots$}

\begin{document}
\section{What you have:}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ TestAlgorithm \newline
\textbf{SomeInputs} input1, \newline $\cdots$ input2, input3, input4, \newline $\cdots$ input5, input6, input7 \newline
\textbf{AnOutput} output1 }
\label{algo:TestAlgorithm A}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $oh yeah!$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\section{What you want:}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ TestAlgorithm \newline
\textbf{SomeInputs} input1, \newline \protect\phantom{$\cdots$} input2, input3, input4, \newline \protect\phantom{$\cdots$} input5, input6, input7 \newline
\textbf{AnOutput} output1 }
\label{algo:TestAlgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $oh yeah!$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ TestAlgorithm \newline
\textbf{SomeInputs} input1, \newline \protect\phantom{$\cdots$} input2, input3, input4, \newline \hspace*{\WidthOfCdots} input5, input6, input7 \newline
\textbf{AnOutput} output1 }
\label{algo:TestAlgorithm B}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $oh yeah!$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Comparison of horizontal spaces:\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\,| & "\," \\
\verb|\thinspace| & "\thinspace" \\
\verb|\enspace| & "\enspace" \\
\verb|\quad| & "\quad" \\
\verb|\qquad| & "\qquad" \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this is a very convolute method for adding some space at the beginning of a line. Would you like to add some hints on how to do it more efficiently?

Comment: @egreg: Added `\hspace` version, but the `\phantom` seems easier to me. Or were you thinking of some other method?  Of course that is assuming there was some reason the OP wanted exactly that specific width.

Comment: From what the OP says, `$\cdots$` is just something that occupies some space. I'd say simply `\quad` or `\qquad`, which are the traditional ways, or `\hspace*{...}` if one wants finer control.

Comment: Ok, have updated solution. I guess I use `\phantom` so often that I assumed there was a reason why the space equal to $cdots$ was required...

Comment: `\settowidth` doesn't require `calc`; the traditional `em` is the width of (capital) "M".

Answer (score 3):

A typesetting system like LaTeX surely has methods for producing white spaces in its output.

The traditional lengths used by (human) printers were called "quad" and "double quad"; the name derives from the Italian "quadrato", that is, "square". It was a piece of metal with a flat square surface that could be inserted among the characters to be set, with its side equal to the font size. The analog of the quad space in TeX is called `\quad` and the double quad is `\qquad`.

However, `\quad` and `\qquad` produce a space that disappears at line breaks, but there are ways to produce a space that *doesn't* disappear. The general spacing command (in horizontal direction) is `\hspace` and `\quad` is equivalent to `\hspace{1em}`; the *-variant of `\hspace` is what we need here:

So your input would be

```
\caption{TestAlgorithm\newline
  \textbf{SomeInputs} input1,\newline
  \hspace*{1em}input2, input3, input4,\newline
  \hspace*{1em}input5, input6, input7\newline
  \textbf{AnOutput} output1}
```

or with `2em` instead of `1em` if you prefer a double quad.

The argument to `\hspace` can be any legal dimension. The `em` unit is font dependent and it's better to stick with it, if there are no other reasons (in some cases an explicit length such as `3cm` or `2in` may be required).