# Differences in spacings

Tags: spacing

I noticed that I can use `\` to produce a spacing in math environment that seems to me equal to the one produced by `\quad`. Where is the difference?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the situations? There are several reasons why "backslash-space" can give more space than expected in math.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/10898

Comment: @azetina Werner's answer there is good but doesn't address this question about `\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- i've just posted a comment suggesting its addition to werner's answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Point taken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The spacing is not at all similar:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\showoutput
$a\ b\quad c$

\end{document}
```

produces

```
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 a
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\glue 10.00002
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 c
```

which shows that `\quad` produces a fixed space (10pt here) but `\` produces the normal inter-word space from the current text font. Which here is stretchy between 2 2/9 pt and 5pt, and would, if necessary stretch more than that.

Answer (score 7):

If you type `\⍽` (backslash space) in math mode, you get an interword space *in addition* to the space TeX could automatically insert. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a\ a>\ a$

$a\ a\;{>}\quad a$
\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

As you see, `\⍽` in the first line doesn't produce a space as wide as `\quad`; but there are two `\⍽` in the first line, that seem to output different spaces.

What happens is that the first `\⍽` is between two ordinary symbols, where TeX does not add any space. But it does around a binary relation symbol. In the second line `{>}` makes `>` into an ordinary symbol and I added `\;` in front of it so that the spacing on the left matches the space in the first line. The second `\⍽` in the first line comes *after* the `\;` automatically inserted by TeX after `>`, so it appears to be bigger, but it isn't.

Note also that `\⍽` inserts *flexible* space, so its amount is not fixed and can stretch or shrink together with all other flexible spaces (mostly interword spaces) on the same line.