# Removing spaces placed by \Set command around curly braces

Tags: spacing

The `\Set` command (from the [`braket` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket)) is useful for set builder notation, but it adds spaces before and after the brackets.

Compare `\Set{1, 2, 3}`:

[image: <code>\Set{1, 2, 3}</code>]

To `\{1, 2, 3\}`:

[image: <code>\{1, 2, 3\}</code>]

Looking through the source code, `\Set` seems to add `\,` spaces before and after each curly bracket. How do I temporarily make these spaces zero-width? I'd like to re-define `\set` to be just `\Set` with the spaces taken out, but neither seem to be defined with `\newcommand`.

I tried something like this, but it gets some sort of TeX "stack overflow" (`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`).

```
\renewcommand{\set}[1]{%
    \let \lbrace = \{\!%
    \let \rbrace = \!\}%
%
    \Set{#1}%
%
    \let \lbrace = \{%
    \let \rbrace = \}%
}
```

Even if I do get the redefined command to work, my approach won't account for the other spaces. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Compare \[
        \Set{1, 2, 3}
    \]
%
    To \[
        \{1, 2, 3\}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not simply `\newcommand\Set#1{\{#1\}}` if that's the layout you want?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `\Set` lets you write `\Set{ x \in S | x > 0 }`, which is equivalent to `\left\{\, x \in S \mid x > 0 \,\right\}`.

Comment: What about `\newcommand{\SET}[1]{\Set{\!#1\!}}` and use `\SET` instead?

Comment: @Werner: That works, thank you. I'm going to see if there are any more generic answers, but if there aren't, I'm definitely using this.

Comment: @Werner -\medmuskip rather than \! (which is -\thinmuskip) I think (see my answer)

Comment: Since nobody else has said it, I will remark that you can't `\let` a command equal to more than one token. Instead of `\let\lbrace\{\!`, you would need `\def\lbrace{\{\!}`, although that wouldn't work either: LaTeX defines `\{` in terms of `\lbrace` and trying to define `\lbrace` in terms of `\{` leads to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

As shown below, the space is `\:` so you can negate that by redefining the command as

```
\renewcommand\Set[1]{%
    \csname Set \endcsname{\mskip-\medmuskip#1\mskip-\medmuskip}}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Compare \[
        \Set{1, 2, 3}
    \]
   \noindent Compare \[\let\:\relax
        \Set{1, 2, 3}
    \]
%
    To \[
        \{1, 2, 3\}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `\Set` includes a [`\medmuskip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) `\:` around its argument (from [`braket.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/braket/braket.sty)):

```
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Set \endcsname#1{\left\{%
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
     \:{\let\|\SetDoubleVert
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\:\right\}}
```

Note the use of `\:` after `\left\{` and before `\right\}`. You can redefine remove this using an alternative `\SET` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand{\SET}[1]{\Set{\mskip-\medmuskip #1 \mskip-\medmuskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \texttt{\detokenize{\Set}}: & $\Set{1, 2, 3}$ \\
  \texttt{\{1, 2, 3\}}: & $\{1, 2, 3\}$ \\
  \texttt{\detokenize{\SET}}: & $\SET{1, 2, 3}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, redefine `\Set` to suit your needs by including this *after* you load `braket`:

```
{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname set \endcsname#1{\mathinner
        {\lbrace\,{\mathcode`\|32768\let|\midvert #1}\,\rbrace}}
  \xdef\Set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Set \endcsname#1{\left\{%
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
     {\let\|\SetDoubleVert
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\right\}}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For strange reason, `braket` uses `\:` for `\Set`, where `\,` would be sufficient.

I propose to redefine the commands with a *-variant that suppresses the spaces next to the braces (and with `\,` in the “big” form).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket,xparse}

\begingroup
\catcode`\|=\active
\gdef\changebarto#1{\mathcode`\|="8000 \let|#1}
\endgroup

\RenewDocumentCommand{\set}{sm}{%
  \mathinner{%
    \lbrace
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\,}%
    {\changebarto\midvert #2}%
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\,}%
    \rbrace
  }%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Set}{sm}{%
  \left\lbrace
    \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\,}%
    {\let\|\SetDoubleVert\changebarto\SetVert #2}%
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\,}%
  \right\rbrace
}

\begin{document}
$\set{1,2,3}\ne\set*{1,2,3}$

$\set{x|x\notin x}$

$\displaystyle\Set{x|x\ne\frac{1}{2}}$

$\displaystyle\Set*{x|x\ne\frac{1}{2}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "For some strange reason..." -- I think it's related to conventional Dirac notation for `\bra`, `\ket`, `\braket`, etc...

Comment: @Mico `\:` is definitely too wide, and `\set`–`\Set` have nothing to do with Dirac's notation. They are in the package just because they were in the same style as `\bra` and `\ket`.

Comment: Thanks. I was always wondering how the `\set` and `\Set` macros wandered into the `braket` package.