# How do I get a heading in the upper right hand corner of the first page only?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I'm looking to do homework in LaTeX. I'd like the format to be as follows: A simple enumerated list of the answers (with simple numbers on the same line, not section markers) with a heading on the top right corner of the first page only. I'd also like smaller margins and 12pt font. The list, the margins, and the font I've taken care of with

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

 \item[1.] Here is some text. $$f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h).$$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to get a heading in the upper right hand corner of the first page. I searched through old answers on the site with no success.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: @Werner Thank you! In practice, I always use `align` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is technically no need to place what you're after in the page *header*. I would just set it as part of the text block - the first thing on the first page, flush right:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\null\hfill\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
  \textbf{My name} \\
  \textit{My University}
\end{tabular}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Here is some text. $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + \mathcal{O}(h)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I've used [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set the page boundary/size. Adjust to your liking. The idea behind a `tabular` is only to emphasize that you can make a *construction* of what you want to place as your "header" that contain multiple lines. However, if you just want a single entry, there may be no need for using `tabular`.

Comment: I like this idea a lot! When you write `\null\hfill\begin{tabular}{t]{l@{}}`, I'm assuming that's all standard `tabular` stuff I can find at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment? Thanks

Comment: @EricAuld: `\null` sets an anchor in the text (which is just an empty, zero-width box. `\hfill` then inserts a [horizontal fill](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) to make whatever follows flush with the right margin. What follows is just a block created using `tabular`, for which you can find information in the link you provided.

Comment: I am in a similar predicament as the OP, but I would like my name to show up each page of the homework. Is there any way to get that table into a header so it is replicated on all pages?

Comment: @kingledion: Sure. Add `\usepackage{fancyhdr} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \fancyhead[R]{<tab>} \setlength{\headheight}{2\baselineskip}` and fill in whatever for `<tab>`.

Comment: @Werner Wow, thanks for the quick response. I had to up the \headheight to 4 to keep the header on the page, but it worked great.

Comment: @kingledion: Yes. If it's too short, you'll see a warning in your `.log`. Set it to at least that.