# \upbracefill filling entire tabular cell and package colortbl

Tags: tables, colortbl

In my documents, I have found that when I call `\upbracefill` in a tabular cell, the resulting brace IS NOT taking the entire width of the cell.

After creating the smallest example I could that produces this behavior (appended below), I have found that the problem has been the inclusion of the package colortbl.

When I remove this package from one of my documents, the brace resulting from  `\upbracefill` DOES FILL the entire width of the cell.

For my documents, however, I need the package [`colortbl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/colortbl).

Attached is an example which replicates this behavior. You can try building this small document both ways, with and without the line `\usepackage{colortbl}`.

I need the normal behavior of `\upbracefill` to fill an entire cell. How can I do this with the package `colortbl`?

I am using LaTeX Version 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2014/dev)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{colortbl} % TRY COMMENTING THIS OUT, TOO

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{  l llll llll }

letters: & a  & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\

blah          & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\upbracefill}    \\
blah          & \multicolumn{8}{l}{\upbracefill}    \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can construct this `\upbracefill` manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{9}{l} }
  letters: & a  & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
  blah     & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\underbrace{\phantom{abcdefgh}\hspace*{14\tabcolsep}}$}} \\
  blah     & \multicolumn{8}{l}{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\underbrace{\phantom{abcdefgh}\hspace*{14\tabcolsep}}$}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Using a `\phantom` hides the equivalent column entries, while there are 2 `\tabcolsep`s between each column. If the measurements become a little unwieldy, you can insert lengths to roughly match the width, like `\hspace*{12.5em}` in this case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{9}{l} }
  letters: & a  & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
  blah     & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\underbrace{\phantom{abcdefgh}\hspace*{14\tabcolsep}}$}} \\
  blah     & \multicolumn{8}{l}{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\underbrace{\hspace*{12.5em}}$}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For more on horizontal widths, see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: Mr. Grundlingh, please take a look at
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/latexusersgroup/i-v1f3dVLjc

Comment: Thank you for your suggested work arounds.  In addition,
someone from latexproject.org sent me another work around, using the following command to make a bracket fill up an entire cell:

\def\hfill{\hskip0pt plus 1filll}\upbracefill

It can be confirmed that the package colortbl currently breaks \upbracefill, though colortbl currently is not part of the core latex release.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
% \usepackage{colortbl} % the output is the same with or without colortbl

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{9}{l}}
  letters: & a  & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
  blah     & \\
  blah     & \\
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[yshift=-2mm]{1-2}{2-9}{}
  \UnderBrace[yshift=-2mm]{1-2}{3-9}{}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same with or without the package `colortbl` (however, `nicematrix` has its own tools to color cells, rows and columns).

[image: Output of the above code]