# How to leave spaces in a formula

Tags: math-mode, spacing, logic

I want a space in between the variables in this formula (monadic first order temporal logic). I tried using `\,` and `\hspace{}` but both do not seem to work. Can somebody help me out?
sample formula:

```
$G(\forall  (x) \forall (y)(p(x) \vee \neg p(y)))$
```

It should be

```
G space(\forall  (x)space \forall (y)space(p(x)space \vee space \neg p(y)))
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo which is not visible in the MWE and has been found by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a difference. Here are 5 versions of your formula, with the normal spacing, and adding `\,`, `\:`, `\;`  and `\`. In my opinion, the only places that might justify adding some space are just between the quantifiers. For the parentheses and the binary symbol, spacing is fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  G\Bigl(\forall (x)\forall (y)\bigl(p(x) \vee\neg p(y)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
  G\,\Bigl(\forall (x)\,\forall (y)\,\bigl(p(x)\,\vee\,\neg p(y)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
  G\:\Bigl(\forall (x)\: \forall (y)\: \bigl(p(x)\: \vee\:\neg p(y)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
  G\;\Bigl(\forall (x)\;\forall (y)\;\bigl(p(x)\;\vee\;\neg p(y)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
  G\ \Bigl(\forall (x)\ \forall (y)\ \bigl(p(x)\ \vee\ \neg p(y)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't see any problem here. Does none of these work for you? Just in order to give some examples. You can find a big list [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{$G#1(\forall(x)#1\forall(y)#1(p(x)#1\vee#1\neg{}p(y)))$\par}

\begin{document}
\test{}
\test{\,}
\test{\>}
\test{\ }
\test{\mkern+10mu}
\test{\quad}
\test{\qquad}
\test{\hskip 3em}
\test{\hspace{35pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can add these commands directly in your formula and use various in each line.

Comment: I'm guessing that line 4 is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I figured it out, the \usepackage{mathtools} had a typo. Thanks.