# Aligning two different align* environments

Tags: align

My question is, how can I get the two different `align*` environments to agree on the equal signs being centred for all six equations on the page (even though there is a line of text breaking them into groups of three and three):

[image: see picture below =]]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `amsmath` provides `intertext` for stuff like that. If the line is part of an itemize environment it gets more complicated.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Im so sorry! Will do that if I post another question! Never used this site before.  It was part of the itemize environment, so it seems the second solution below is applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    E(M) &= A\\
    E(A) &= 180-B-C\\
    E(N) &= A/2 - B/2 - C/2 + 90
    \intertext{(b) The variances are given by:}
    \var(M) &= 1\\
    \var(A) &= 1/2\\
    \var(N) &= 3/4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**:

If the other commentators are right and you are inside an `itemize` environment, a very easy solution would be to define your own indent. Not super fancy, but clear and easy.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}
\newcommand*{\myIndent}{\hspace{4cm}} % or whatever space you may find on http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[(a)] Whatever you have written in item (a):
    \begin{flalign*}
    \myIndent\mathllap{E(M)} &= A&\\
    E(A) &= 180-B-C\\
    E(N) &= A/2 - B/2 - C/2 + 90
    \end{flalign*}
    \item[(b)] The variances are given by:
    \begin{flalign*}
    \myIndent\mathllap{\var(M)} &= 1&\\
    \var(A) &= 1/2\\
    \var(N) &= 3/4
    \end{flalign*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update 2**:

daleif brought me to the idea to use `\item` directly in `\intertext` (or `\shortintertext`, if you prefer the vertical spacing). You will need at least one `\item` outside the `align` in order to get that working.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{align*}
        E(M) &= A\\
        E(A) &= 180-B-C\\
        E(N) &= A/2 - B/2 - C/2 + 90
        \intertext{\item The variances are given by:}
        \var(M) &= 1\\
        \var(A) &= 1/2\\
        \var(N) &= 3/4
    \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the `(b)` is part of some enumerated environment, which makes things a bit more tricky than this. `;-)`

Comment: @PaulGessler I fear the same... Well, We'll have to wait for the MWE.

Comment: Just as a test I tried `\intertext{\item ...}`, that actually seems to be working!!! Though with a bit excessive text

Comment: @daleif cool, that is surprising! I will stand corrected if it does indeed work like that.

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I put that to my answer. If you want to write an answer by yourself, I will delete that afterwards.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, just add it to yours. BTW: by exessive I meant the spacing above and below

Comment: Thank everyone so much. I was using the enumerate package, but this seems to have done the trick.