# Algorithmic in Latex

Tags: algorithms

I want to write:

```
{Step 6 
  for n = 0 to final do
  y(n) = x(n)
  e(k) = d(k)  y(k)
  w(n + 1) = w(n) + x(n)e(n)
  end for}
```

My problem is `for` appears in the start without identation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `minted` package for code, which also provides syntax [highligthing](https://code.google.com/p/minted/). Alternative you can create custom spaces with `\quad` or `\qquad` or `\hspace{2mm}` or `~`, [among some other ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing).