# How to align superscripts?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, superscripts

I have an expression like

```
$$\eta^{[\alpha\beta}_{\phantom{\alpha\beta}\rho}h^{\sigma]}A^\rho$$
```

and I would like that all the indices alpha, beta, sigma and rho appear on a same line. If someone have a suggestion it will be great!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Do you want those [] to be rendered? What do they mean? Please do not use `$$ $$` but `\[ \]` as the first is deprecated since years.

Comment: Without those brackets, `\[\eta^{\alpha\beta}_{\rho}h^{\sigma}A^\rho\]` should be just fine. If it isn't, you will have to show us an MWE please!

Comment: Hmmm... I can't really parse this expression --- can't really see what it "means" mathematically. Is the $h$ multiplying $\alpha\beta$ and has a pre-subindex $\rrho$ and exponent $\sigma$? or is $\sigma$ with two left-subindex multiplying $\alpha\beta$? I suggest a rewrite ;-)

Answer (score 6):

What you need is `\hphantom` instead of just a `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
   \eta^{[\alpha\beta}_{\hphantom{\alpha\beta}\rho}h^{\sigma]}A^\rho
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the `\phantom` term is omitted, the superscript terms will be aligned correctly without further ado. The following screenshot shows (a) your original expression, (b) a first alternative that features the subscript `\rho` term far from `\eta`, and (c) a second alternative where the `\rho` subscript is placed closer to `\eta`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin {align*}
\text{Orig.}\qquad &
\eta^{[\alpha\beta}_{\phantom{\alpha\beta}\rho}h^{\sigma]}A^\rho\\
\text{Alt.\ 1} \qquad&
{\eta^{[\alpha\beta}}_{\mkern-8mu\rho} \, h^{\sigma]} A^\rho\\
\text{Alt.\ 2} \qquad&
\eta^{[\alpha\beta}_{\rho} h^{\sigma]} \! A^\rho
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not ideal, but you could add a `\mystrut` to every base and embrace `{}` the base.  EDITED to address barbara's concern by making the strut a custom `\mystrut` that does not go below the baseline.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\def\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{\the\ht\strutbox}}
\begin{document}
\[{\mystrut\eta}^{[\alpha\beta}_{\phantom{\alpha\beta}\rho}
  {\mystrut h}^{\sigma]}{\mystrut A}^\rho\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the subscripted `\rho` is lower; that's not really desirable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton addressed with a custom upward-only `\mystrut`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular construction, you can set the sub-script to `\eta` as separate sub-script to `{}` (nothing). The combination of the super- and sub-script is causing a vertical shift of the scripts:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \eta^{[\alpha\beta} \!\! {}_\rho \, h^{\sigma]} A^\rho
\]

\end{document}
```

I've added some [horizontal spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/5764) to simulate the [dis]association of the `\rho` sub-script with `\eta` [`h`], but that's up to personal preference.