# A canonical or robust white space thinner than \,?

Tags: spacing

I'm looking for a white space  thinner than `\,`.

- Is there a canonical one? (By canonical, I mean an  already built in command)
- If not, how to define a robust white space twice thiner than `\,`?

Comment: See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/110998) for an overview of all spacing commands. There you also find `\kern`, `\hspace` and `\hskip` which take a user-defined length as argument.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command `\,` is defined to use `\thinspace` (0.16667em) in text mode and `\thinmuskip` (3.0mu) in math mode , so we can make a half-size one with

```
\protected\def\verythinspace{%
  \ifmmode
    \mskip0.5\thinmuskip
  \else
    \ifhmode
      \kern0.08334em
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

(The math mode distance is stored as a variable, so we can do the calculation on-the-fly, whereas `\thinspace` hard-codes the distance.)

Comment: Since you added robustness, you could also protect the macro against being in vertical mode. There was a question in the GuIT forum about a strange behavior of `\,`: the user was using it before starting a paragraph.

Comment: For those readers who aren't quite sure how wide a `mu` is: By default, `18mu=1em`. Thus also, `3mu=0.16667em`. :-)