# What command produces a "normal" space?

Tags: spacing

I'd like to add a "normal" space, where the length of the space is the same as the length of the space between the words you are reading right now.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: An escaped space ``\ ``. That is <backslash> <space>

Comment: Or you can use `\space`.

Comment: Perhaps better to close as a duplicate of [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353)

Comment: @Alan Munn I'm asking about a specific space command, not asking for a list of all of them.

Comment: Yes, but item 13 in the accepted answer gives you the answer you're looking for. On some stacks there is an accepted policy of answers can make questions dupes, i.e. if the answer is to be found somewhere under an existing question, the new question is closed as dupe. Many people have strong feelings about this and we don't tend to do that here. However, as all the information you need and more is already to be found on this site, this question is probably better used as a signpost to that question.

Comment: You can see, I hope, that it would better to have that as a master question and questions like 'how do I get a normal space', 'how do I get a thin space', 'how do I get a 1 em space' (were they all to exist) closed and pointing to that, rather than having that and lots of subquestions existing separately

Comment: Exactly. Fundamentally this is no different a question that "how do I produce *this symbol*", for which rather than having a huge number of individual questions/answers we redirect to a general question about looking up symbols.

Comment: @Au101 The answer you linked does not seem to explicitly mention the normal word space is #13, I only knew it was #13 because you told me it was. I could have posted my question as a comment under that answer, I guess, but the first answer to my question already has some people disagreeing which commands produces the space I want. It might not be #13 after all, and it might equally indeed be that, and I posted that thought as a separate question. If you think a simple comment would suffice, let me know and I'll delete this question.

Comment: No no *please* don't delete duplicate questions, they're useful. Now, somebody looking for a normal space will find this question and be able to follow the link to that question. This is good. Closing as duplicate isn't a punishment, the worst thing it can do is slightly depress the rep that you might have got. This is an unfortunate side-effect, but we like them, because they act as sign posts and now, with this comment thread and the answer, it will be clear to others how to get the answer out of that question. But it doesn't make sense to have this question open in terms of organisation

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. A simple way would be to use `~` or `\`  this would give an extra gap the size of one space. I would also recommend seeing this question: [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353)

Example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\noindent
text spacing\\
text ~spacing\\
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Note that LaTeX often does spacing automatically to eliminate line breaks so in a document the regular space between words can vary.

Comment: `\:\:` is not the same as a word space, this answer is at best misleading

Comment: without amsmath.amsart (which is not mentioned in the question) `\:` is an error in text mode, and with it it is a horizontal space of a different size to `\space`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I was writing it I tried to make the space the width of a character. Which was a mistake. I will edit it to make it only have ``\:``. Thanks

Comment: no `\:` is wrong you need to edit the answer _not_ to have `\:`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope my new edit makes this answer satisfactory. I replaced ``\:`` with ``~``.

Comment: It's better but it would have been better just to say use `\ ` as was correctly said already in the comments under the question. Why imply `\ ` is just for math mode? (it should not normally be used in math mode) unlike `\:` which by default can _only_ be used in math mode.

Comment: `~` isn't just any old space, though, it's a *non-breaking space* - it prevents a line-break at that point