# Why am I getting the error of missing '$'

Tags: errors, symbols

This is my line, it is giving me a missing character error

> Missing $ inserted.
>    $
>
> l.43 ...l a, b \in \BQ, x = a + b\mbox{\sqrt[]{2}}
>                                                     $

```
$\forall a, b \in \BQ, x = a + b\mbox{\sqrt[]{2}}$
```

the `\mbox` is for making the `\sqrt` play nicely with the `b` before it

Comment: What is `\BQ` command?

Comment: \newcommand{\BQ}{\mathbb Q} just to make my life easier.

Comment: You've put `\sqrt` in text mode (inside a box): it's not clear to me why ...

Comment: ive had issues working with \sqrt in math more, it just intersects with anything before it. Is there a better way to format it?

Comment: Firstly, I don't know why you should use `\mbox` to get something `nicer` in this case; secondly, you better ask your question via an `MWE`; thirdly, this code generates what you want, doesn't it?! `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$(\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Q}) x = a + b\sqrt{2}$

\end{document} `

Comment: all of a sudden even without the mbox its giving me the same error

Comment: Yeah problem solved, i was just being stupid.

Comment: The wrong placement of the radical seems due to `[]`, avoid it when no index is needed. So `\sqrt{2}` and `\sqrt[3]{3}`, but not `\sqrt[]{2}`.

Comment: if you are typesetting math in inline mode it is always good to split it into small parts surrounded by `$$`, like egreg did in his answer. I don't mean doing `$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$` -- it is tottally wrong, but splitting sentence into logical parts will give you better spacing and less problems with linebreaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\mbox` switches to text mode, so if you put `\sqrt` inside you need include it in `$...$`: `\mbox{$\sqrt{2}$}`.

However, if you just want some extra space before (or after) `\sqrt` it is much better to stay in math mode and just add `\,` at the appropriate place, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Q}, x = a + b\,\sqrt{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

This allows `\sqrt{...}` to fit with the surrounding math style.

See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/15925) for a full list of available spacing commands.

Comment: Ive removed the box and still have the missing $ issue

>Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> $
                
>l.44         $\forall
                      a, b \in \BQ, x = a + b\,\sqrt[]{2}$

Comment: Then the error is from earlier in your document.  The code in my answer compiles without error.

Comment: youre exactly right. i missed it somewhere else. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error is in `\mbox{\sqrt[]{2}}`, because `\mbox` switches to text mode.

However, this seems a consequence of another mistake: for implementation reasons, an empty optional argument to `\sqrt` causes the symbol to be misplaced. Avoid `\sqrt[]{2}` and use the correct `\sqrt{2}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\BQ}{\mathbb{Q}} % <--- with braces

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
Wrong:  & $\forall a, b \in \BQ, x = a + b\sqrt[]{2}$ \\
Better: & $\forall a, b \in \BQ, x = a + b\sqrt{2}$   \\
Best:   & for all $a, b \in \BQ$, $ x = a + b\sqrt{2}$
\end{tabular}

\medskip

Cube roots don't have the problem: $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I prefer not to use `\forall`, but in any case, it should be two formulas: `$\forall a,b\in\BQ$, $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$`.

Note also that the correct syntax is `\mathbb{Q}` instead of `\mathbb Q`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the OP's full sentence contains -- and thus should be typeset with -- two separate formulas: `$a, b \in \BQ$` and `$x = a + b\sqrt{2}$`. :-)