# What is the difference between ~ (tilde) and \, (backslash comma) for a nonbreaking space?

Tags: spacing, tilde, comparison

Regarding tiny nonbreaking spaces, is there a difference between using a `~` (tilde) and using `\,` (backslash comma)? If so, what is the difference, in terms of length, properties, situations where you would use one over the other, etc.?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference between a normal unbreakable space and a thin unbreakable space: `\,` is `1/6em`, while `~` is, if I'm  not mistaken, what TeX denotes `\fontdimen2`, the interword space.

Comment: I see. So the length of `\,` is fixed, but that of `~` is not. In that case, could `~` be shorter than `\,` in certain instances?

Comment: no, it can only be the interword space as lowest distance

Comment: The length of `\,` is fixed *for a given font*.

Answer (score 11):

`5~kg` will not be broken across lines but can be stretched, if needed by TeX: `5   kg`. `5\,kg` cannot be stretched.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify, can `\,` be broken across lines? I was not clear from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing if this was the case.

Comment: no linebreak possible