# Betti table in Latex

Tags: tables

I want to draw a Betti table in Latex.

I tried this

```
\begin{table}[h!]

  \begin{center}

    \label{tab:table1}

    \begin{tabular}{l|c}

      &  & 1...s \hline\\

      i &\beta_{0,i} \beta_{1,i+1}...\beta_{s,i+s} \\

      i+1&\beta_{0,i+1} \beta_{1,i+2}...\beta_{s,i+s+1}\\

      ...&.......................................\\
      j&\beta_{0,j}\beta{1,j+1}...\beta_{s,j+s}

    \end{tabular}

  \end{center}

\end{table}
```

but it doesn't look as a Betti table.

It should be like this https://www.google.ro/search?tbm=isch&q=betti+table+minimal+resolution+algebraic+geometry+examples&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS463QyNXYAhWL2ywKHX0dD3cQBQg7KAA&biw=1024&bih=662&dpr=1#imgrc=OhNaCj1wqyz3RM.

Comment: The image has no `\beta` whatsoever; please, add an approximate representation of the output you're expecting.

Comment: Problemsolving why can you not show an  image of the expected output? A google search will give different results for different people. For me it [gives this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iOyI.jpg) which gives no indication of the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to spare others the error messages they'll receive when they try to run your snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]


    \[\begin{array}{l|c}
        & 1\dots s \\ \hline
       i &\beta_{0,i} \beta_{1,i+1}\dots\beta_{s,i+s} \\
      i+1&\beta_{0,i+1} \beta_{1,i+2}\dots\beta_{s,i+s+1}\\
      \vdots&\cdots\cdots\cdots\\\
      j&\beta_{0,j}\beta{1,j+1}\dots\beta_{s,j+s}
    \end{array}
\]
\caption{Labels need to be placed \emph{after} the caption.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, your google link does not show a unique table, so I don't know what you're after. (And I always thought Betti tables would come with more columns.)

Comment: If you follows the link you notice that there is a table on a black band. Your changes solve a part of my problem. I need space between $\beta$-s. How can I do that?

Comment: @Problemsolving: For a list of possibilities to insert horizontal space you can have a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/134144

Comment: @Problemsolving I have problems seeing this table. Instead of posting the result of a google search, why don't you just take a screenshot of the table and post it here?