# mathmode spacing shorter than \quad?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, kerning

Is there a way to get a spacing which is half or quarter the length of \quad in mathmode? 
Maybe there's an easy way to define a shortcut for such command?

Comment: A quad is 1em; just use `\hspace{0.5em}` or `\hspace{0.25em}`. Indeed `\quad` means the same as `\hspace{1em}`.

Comment: @egreg     Thanks. You can post it as an answer, then I'l delete mien, if u want..

Comment: `\enspace` is a half quad, and it works in math mode. Another short spacing command is `\,= \mspace{3 mu}=\hspace{1/6 em}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing the comment from @egreg:

" A quad is 1em; just use \hspace{0.5em} or \hspace{0.25em}. Indeed \quad means the same as \hspace{1em}. – egreg "

Thanks!

Therefore, might or not be helpful for some (for me it is convenient):

```
 \newcommand{\Hquad}{\hspace{0.5em}}
```

Comment: Description of spacing commands

LATEX code Description
\quad space equal to the current font size (= 18 mu)
\, 3/18 of \quad (= 3 mu)
\: 4/18 of \quad (= 4 mu)
\; 5/18 of \quad (= 5 mu)
\! -3/18 of \quad (= -3 mu)
\ (space after backslash!) equivalent of space in normal text
\qquad twice of \quad (= 36 mu)

Comment: @Sebastiano     hmm, can you explain in simple words please?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing

Comment: From @Sebastiano's link, \enspace should give you this half-1em space, either in math mode or in regular mode.

Answer (score 11):

A `\quad` corresponds to a length of `1em`. In math mode, `1em=18mu`. Use `\mkern<n>mu`, where `<n>` can be either a positive or a negative number, to exert very fine control over spacing. Note: no curly braces around `<n>mu`.

To space ahead by half a quad while in math mode, simply write `\mkern9mu`.

Two macros that provide standard abbreviations for math-mode spacing directives are

```
\, -- \mkern3mu  ("thinspace")
\! -- \mkern-3mu ("negative thinspace")
```

Is there a meaningful difference between `a\hspace{0.5em}b` and `a\mkern9mu b`? It usually will *not* make a difference for display-math material. However, it could make a difference for inline-math material. This is because TeX never discards explicit kerns (and `\mkern` is a kern); in contrast, `\hspace` *could* get discarded at the start and end of lines. Thus, if your document happens to have a longish inline math equation that's allowed to break across lines, using `\mkern` or `\hspace` inside the formula could make a difference. (If you wanted to allow potential line breaks while using mu-based spacing directives, don't use `\mkern`; instead, use `\mskip` instead.)

Comment: Mico, Hi. I think that the question is similar or duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks for this pointer. I've voted to close the query as a duplicate.