# How to italicize enumeration in task environment

Tags: italic, emphasis, tasks

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\itshape](4)
    \task Ex. 1
    \task Ex. 2
    \task Ex. 3
    \task Ex. 4
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: With italics]

I would like to **not** italicize the parentheses:

[image: Without italics]

Is it possible to achieve it in an easy way?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this can provide you some ideas: [Upright parentheses in italic text](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13048)

Comment: @AlanMunn yes! I use `\begin{tasks}[label-format=\itshape,counter-format=tsk[r]\upshape{)}](4)` but now I can't remember how to change the task numbers (*i*, *ii*, *iii* and *iv*) as before (*a*, *b*, *c* and *d*) `:(`. Edit: NVM, changed `tsk[r]` to `tsk[a]` `:)`. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: No, it's fine for you to post a self-answer.  I just gave a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should use `\textup{)}`, so the italic correction would be automatically added; unfortunately, this crashes because of the nature of `\textup` that doesn't really like to be used in that place. However, there's an easy fix.

Note that `\upshape` *doesn't* take an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\textup}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[label-format=\itshape,counter-format=tsk[a]\upshape{)}](4)
    \task Ex. 1
    \task Ex. 2
    \task Ex. 3
    \task Ex. 4
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label-format=\itshape,counter-format=tsk[a]\/\upshape)](4)
    \task Ex. 1
    \task Ex. 2
    \task Ex. 3
    \task Ex. 4
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[label-format=\itshape,counter-format=tsk[a]\textup{)}](4)
    \task Ex. 1
    \task Ex. 2
    \task Ex. 3
    \task Ex. 4
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

You can see that the second and third examples print the same. In the second example, the italic correction `\/` is explicitly added.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@AlanMunn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) for the hint.

I added the `\upshape` command only for the parentheses and used `tsk[a]` for *a*, *b*, *c*, ... style numbers, all inside `counter-format` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\itshape,counter-format=tsk[a]\upshape{)}](4)
    \task Ex. 1
    \task Ex. 2
    \task Ex. 3
    \task Ex. 4
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: Right parentheses]

Comment: You should italicize both the counter `a,b,..` and the `)`, look at the _d_), either you italicize both or add a small space between the counter and the paren. In your case, it's the latter choice as done in the image with red arrows.

Comment: @AboAmmar I would like to keep the actual style. I use `\upshape{ )}` but the space is too large, and then `\upshape{$\,$)}` but is the same space. Also tried with `\upshape{~)}`. What do you recommend?

Comment: A `\,` might be nice, in case you need to try many variants, [see this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/59109) about horizontal spaces in LaTeX.

Comment: @AboAmmar woo excellent! Anyway `\,` isn't the same space of, for example, `\begin{enumerate}` with *a*), *b*), etc.

Comment: You can try with math mode: `$\mkern1.5mu)$` (`\,` is 3mu).