# Closing an indefinite number of brackets

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I found myself in the precarious situation of having to open many brackets on one side of the equation which are then closed one by one, as in the following example:

```
  \left( \cdots \left( \left( A_1 \right) * A_2 \right) \cdots \right) * A_n.
```

The product here is not associative and requires bracketing.

The ellipsis on the left hand side looks ugly to me, too spacious. Is there a more suitable command to do what I'm trying to do here? Would you approach this problem in a different way?

Comment: First of all, you don't need `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question here? Also, if you're concerned about using `\cdots`, you should probably also consider using something other than `*` (perhaps `\times`).

Comment: I would show at least up to `A_3`, as in `( \cdots ( ( ( A_1 ) * A_2 ) * A_3 ) \cdots ) * A_n.`.

Comment: Does it seem better with `{\cdots}` (with the braces)?

Comment: @egreg I trimmed the actual content where A_i are long expressions and * is of the form \times_{other long expression}. Hence the need for \left \right. The use of {\cdots} didn't do anything for me, did they make a difference for you?

Comment: @Werner An indefinite (or perhaps indeterminate) number of brackets all have to be closed on the left. Also, yes, in reality \times is being used, here I'm trying to keep the notation to a minimum. I was sure there was a symbol for (...( as in \dotsint which does it for multiple integrals.

Comment: @Emre: If the spacing around `\cdots` doesn't meet your needs, then you can adjust it. See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) For example, you can use `\!\!\cdots\!\!`...

Comment: @Werner Thanks, that's a good tip and gets rid of the excess spacing around \cdots. Do you know if there is a way to coerce the three dots coming from \cdots to compress together as well?

Comment: @Emre: Indeed. You can use `\!\!{\cdot}{\cdot}{\cdot}\!\!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the spacing around symbols just the way you please. Using some [negative spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) and braces around `\cdot`s, you can create `\tightcdots`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tightcdots}{\!\!{\cdot}{\cdot}{\cdot}\!\!}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left( \cdots \left( \cdots \left( \frac{A}{2} \right) \times A_2 \right) \cdots \right) \times A_n.
\]

\[
  \left( \tightcdots \left( \tightcdots \left( \frac{A}{2} \right) \times A_2 \right) \tightcdots \right) \times A_n.
\]

\end{document}
```