# White horizontal space

Tags: spacing

I know the possible ways to add white space between two texts, as explained and answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing).
What I'm struggling to set is a white space before one word, nothing that I tried worked except this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{white}{
        \parbox{\textwidth}{
            Usage: export.py \\
            \begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
                & Save the ...

    \end{tabular}}}
\end{document}
```

My question is: can I get this output from the line in a different way or this is the only way to have a white space before a word? [image]

EDIT: update the code; the everything is inside a `parbox` and I cannot use `\quad`, `\qquad` or `\hspace`.

EDIT2: I need to create a box with inside the option for a script in a similar way they are presented in the terminal:

[image]

Comment: You can add some horizontal predefined space with `\quad` for example. Or more general, `\hspace{1cm}` (use with caution).

Comment: Explain better what you wish. There could be a better way to type it. For example, move `Usage:` in the first cell of the table and `export.py` to the second cell, 1st row.

Comment: isn't this a description list, something like `\begin{description} \item[export.py] Save the ...` then with suitable style for the list item labels being applied?

Comment: I update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but, just a starting point for you:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \color{white}
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{black}{
        \parbox{\textwidth}{
            \begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
                Usage:& export.py \\
                & Save the ...\\
                Options:&\\
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{-h,}&-{}-help    \\      
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{-p,}&-{}-please continue\\
                    \multicolumn{1}{r}{-f,}&-{}-from here\\
    \end{tabular}}}
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]