# Using `\left(` and `right)` puts a space after an operator

Tags: spacing, delimiters

When I use `\left(` and `\right)` to get appropriately sized parentheses for an operator, a space is created between the operator and the parentheses. I think it looks bad. Is it intentional? If so, why? If not, is it easy to 'repair'?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{align*}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \log(a) &= 0\\
    \log\left(a\right) &= 0\\
    \log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: A left-right pair forms an "inner" construction, and the operator sees that as a symbol and inserts a space. Often it is better to just scale manually, using the `\bigl` and `\bigr`variants (there are four left and four right), which also classifies as open/close and thus no space is inserted. For the autoscaled, see the `mleftright` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  the `\mleft ...`mright` pair also yields  a correct spacing. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{align*}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \log(a) &= 0\\
    \log\left(a\right) &= 0\\
    \log\mleft(a\mright) &= 0\\
    \log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) &= 0\\
    \log\mleft(\frac{a}{b}\mright) &= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The space looks good. But if you still want to decrease the space between the operator and the parentheses, a quick method is to use a negative space, `\!`. It works in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{align*}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \log(a) &= 0\\
    \ \\
    \log \left(a\right) &= 0\\
    \log\!\left(a\right) &= 0\\
    \ \\
    \log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) &= 0\\
    \log\!\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The result is below.

[image]

This question might also be useful for you: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)