# move table to left side

Tags: tables

Here in my code i want to slightly (approximately 2cm) move table on left side. Is it possible?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage[left=1.300cm, right=1.300cm, top=1.300cm, bottom=1.300cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(A),left=0pt]
\item Calculate for given data.

    \begin{tabular}{|c|              % <---
        *{10}{S{>{$}c<{$}}|}} % <---
    \hline
    $x$ & 43 & 44 & 36 & 38 & 47 & 40 & 41 & 54 & 37 & 46\\ \hline
    $y$ & 74 & 76 & 60 & 68 & 79 & 70 & 71 & 94 & 65 & 78\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is indented because it is inside the item, so you could put it after the list or `\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}....` would move it 2cm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was very simple. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you like to move table to the left text border. As mentioned @DavidCarlisle, table inside list start at `\leftmarigini`, so you need to move for this amount to the left by use of the `\hspace*`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.300cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7pt}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(A),left=0pt]
\item Calculate for given data.

\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\begin{tabular}{% <---
        |c|*{10}{S{>{$}c<{$}}|}}  
    \hline
    $x$ & 43 & 44 & 36 & 38 & 47 & 40 & 41 & 54 & 37 & 46\\ \hline
    $y$ & 74 & 76 & 60 & 68 & 79 & 70 & 71 & 94 & 65 & 78\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

**Addendum:**
What you mean with right side? That the right border of table is aligned with right border of text area? In this case consider @Werner comments below. With it the result of above MWE is:
[image]

Comment: If i want to move the table on right side then only i have to replace left by right?

Comment: @Maths4Sandy: By "right side", are you referring to the right margin? That is, you want the table flush against the right margin? For that, replace `\hspace*{-\leftmargin}` with `\mbox{}\hfill`.

Comment: @Werner As in the solution given by Zarko, table is moved on left side.  i am asking that is it possible to move the table on right side with same distance.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy: You can just insert whatever horizontal space you need. For example, `\hspace*{\leftmargin}` would move it to the *right* in the same amount the `\hspace*{-\leftmargin}` would move it to the *left* (note the negative length). More details on lengths and horizontal movement is available here: [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/5764)

Comment: Got it thanks a lot to Werner.