# code of this picture

Tags: diagrams

[image]

What is the code for write this mapps in this picture?

Comment: If you download papers from the arxiv, it is not hard to get the original tex code for each file. For example, look here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13006 and click on "Other formats". Then click on "source". You should get the original tex file we wrote. That gives you lots of examples of code you can copy from.

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells = {nodes={minimum width=3.5em, inner xsep=0pt}},
                   row sep=0pt]
\rho:G \ar[r]           &   GL(V)   \\
s      \ar[r, mapsto]   &   \rho_s
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) each provide extensible versions of `\rightarrow` and `\mapsto` using `\xrightarrow{<stuff>}` and `\xmapsto{<stuff>}`.

Below I inserted a `1em` space (using `\quad`) as the arguments (`<stuff>`) to both. You can use `\hspace{<len>}` where you specify an appropriate `<len>`gth (see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \rho \colon G &\xrightarrow{\quad} GL(V) \\
              s &\xmapsto{\quad} \rho_s
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\begin{document}
    $\rho:G \longrightarrow GL(V)$

    $s\longmapsto \rho_s$
\end{document}
```

This should reproduce the above picture..

Comment: How to adjust Length of arrow?