# Formatting for a math notation of the form $[a:b]$

Tags: formatting, math-operators

I would like to use a notation for ranges of integers

```
$[a:b] = \{ a, a+1, \dots, b-1, b \}$.
```

However, the spacing of `$[a:b]$` is often not quite satisfying. The colon `:` seems to push the glyphs `a` and `b` very much to the sides, and there is not much space between the square brackets and the numbers.

Which options do I have to type such an integer range? I am particular concerned about the spacing.

Comment: Did you see the posting [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5001) Aside: In math mode, the `:` symbol is of type `mathrel` by default. To eliminate the horizontal whitespace that surrounds objects of type `mathrel`, type either `{:}` or `\mathord{:}`.

Comment: For no space around `:`, type `{:}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit tricky: a simple `\,{:}\,` might seem enough, but there would be problems if the right boundary is a negative number. Thus some precautions are needed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rg}{\mathclose{}{\,{:}\,}\mathopen{}}

\begin{document}

$[a\rg b]$ $[2\rg 5]$ $[-4\rg -2]$

\end{document}
```

[image]