# How to insert a horizontal space?

Tags: spacing

I am aware that there are several ways to insert a horizontal space in a LaTeX document - [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing), but none of them seems to work in my case.

This is the undesired behaviour in my rendered document - 
[image: bad spacing in pdf]

This is my code -

```
\Section{Programming Skills}
\vspace{-5pt}
\textbf{Languages:} Python, Java, C, C++\\
\textbf{Libraries/Frameworks:} numpy, ROOT, git, CUDA, *nix, \LaTeX{}
\vspace{-5pt}
```

where *Languages* is indented more than *Libraries/Frameworks*. Unindenting *Languages* or indenting *Libraries/Frameworks* so that they line up both are fine. (should line up in their current positions, not more to the left or right)

definition of `\Section` is in my .cls -

```
\newcommand{\Section}[1]{
    \Line \par
    \vspace{1pt}
    \textbf{\fontsize{13}{13}\selectfont #1} \par
    \vspace{-7pt}
    \Line \par
    \vspace{3pt}
}
```

Comment: Remove the `\\ ` after "C++".and add an empty line instead.  Additinoally, you can add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to your preamble to get rid of the indentation.

Comment: Replacing the `\\` with `\newline` did not change anything :( 
Adding `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to the preamble fixes this case but messes up indentation in the rest of the file.

Comment: Please make your code fragments compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to put together a compilable version of your code.

```
% secprob.tex  SE 538713

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Section}[1]{
%    \Line % don't know what this is, using \mbox{} instead
    \mbox{} \par
    \vspace{1pt}
    \textbf{\fontsize{13}{13}\selectfont #1} \par
    \vspace{-7pt}
%    \Line 
    \mbox{}\par
    \vspace{3pt}
}

\begin{document}

\Section{Programming Skills}
\vspace{-5pt}
\textbf{Languages:} Python, Java, C, C++ % \\ % just leave an empty line

\textbf{Libraries/Frameworks:} numpy, ROOT, git, CUDA, *nix, \LaTeX{}
\vspace{-5pt}

\end{document}
```

Replacing your `\\` with an empty line gives a result you were asking for.