# How to remove the separator dots in modern cv banking style

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I want to get rid of the separator dots between the details (phones, socials). I assume that I need to make a change in `moderncvheadiii.sty`, but I cannot figure out where I should edit. Can anyone help?

[image]

```
%% start of file `moderncvheadiii.sty'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvheadiii}[2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 3]

% details options: "details" (default) or "nodetails"
\@initializeif{\if@details}\@detailsfalse
\DeclareOption{details}{\@detailstrue}
\DeclareOption{nodetails}{\@detailsfalse}

\DeclareOption*{}% avoid choking on unknown options
\ExecuteOptions{details}
\ProcessOptions*\relax% \ProcessOptions* processes the options in the order provided (i.e., with the later ones possibly overriding the former ones), while \ProcessOptions processes them in the order of the package

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                required packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                overall head definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% fonts
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\Huge\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\normalsize\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}

% commands
\@initializecommand{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
%   internal command to add an element to the footer
%   it collects the elements in a temporary box, and checks when to flush the box
\@initializebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}%
\@initializebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}%
\@initializelength{\makeheaddetailswidth}%
\@initializelength{\makeheaddetailsboxwidth}%
\@initializeif{\if@firstmakeheaddetailselement}\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue%
%   adds an element to the makehead, separated by makeheadsymbol
%   usage: \addtomakehead[makeheadsymbol]{element}
\newcommand*{\addtomakeheaddetails}[2][\makeheaddetailssymbol]{% TODO: use \@initializecommand, which requires modifying its definition to handle mandatory and optional arguments
  \if@firstmakeheaddetailselement%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}{\usebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}#2}%
  \else%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}{\usebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}#1#2}\fi%
  \settowidth{\makeheaddetailsboxwidth}{\usebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}}%
  \ifnum\makeheaddetailsboxwidth<\makeheaddetailswidth%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}{\usebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}}%
    \@firstmakeheaddetailselementfalse%
  \else%
    \flushmakeheaddetails\\%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}{#2}%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}{#2}%
    \settowidth{\makeheaddetailsboxwidth}{\usebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}}%
    \@firstmakeheaddetailselementfalse\fi}
%   internal command to flush the makehead
\@initializecommand{\flushmakeheaddetails}{%
  \strut\usebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}{}%
  \savebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailsboxwidth}{0pt}}
\@initializecommand{\makehead}{%
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\makeheaddetailswidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
        \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
      \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmakeheaddetails}\fi}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makehead


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                resume head definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% lengths
\@initializelength{\quotewidth}
\renewcommand*{\recomputecvheadlengths}{%
  \setlength{\quotewidth}{0.65\textwidth}}

% commands
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{% TODO: use \@initializecommand, which requires modifying its definition to handle \par
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \makehead%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                letter head definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% lengths
%\renewcommand*{\recomputeletterheadlengths}{}

% commands
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender block
  \makehead%
  \par%
   % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}


\endinput


%% end of file `moderncvheadiii.sty'.
```

Comment: Maybe try to remove `\textbullet`.

Answer (score 2):

The seperator dots are defined in this way:

```
\@initializecommand{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
```

There is a inbuild distance (with several `~`) before and after command `\textbullet` (the seperator dot). To get rid of the bullet, but keep the distances use the patch

```
\patchcmd{\makeheaddetailssymbol}
  {\textbullet}% to search
  {}%            replacement
  {}{}%          success failure
```

where `\textbullet` gets simply deleted in the code.

To get rid of the seperator dot and the surrounding distances simple use the command

```
\renewcommand{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{\quad}
```

For an larger distance you can try `\qquad` instead of `\quad`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

%\renewcommand{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{\quad} % <======================== \qquad
\patchcmd{\makeheaddetailssymbol} % <===================================
  {\textbullet}% to search
  {}%            replacement
  {}{}%          success failure <======================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 1):

In order to get rid of the filled circle that separates individual contact details without making any changes to `moderncvheadiii.sty`, you can add

```
\makeatletter
\@initializecommand{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{\quad}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble of your document.

If you want a larger white space between the entries, you can also replace `\quad` with `\qqad`. For more spacing options, you can also take a look here: [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/134144)

Comment: Thank you very much! The associated link is also informative!!