# TeX, LaTeX, space, tab shortcut

Tags: spacing, text, setspace

Is there a better than '\quad' way to style text like on the picture? I mean the space before and after dash. Is using '\quad' after 'inputs:' to make space in next line like after 'tab' a good idea?

```
Inputs:
\\ \quad \quad $G = \langle{V,E}\rangle$ \quad - \quad a weighted graph
\\ \quad \quad $v_ 0$ \quad  - \quad the initial node to determine distances from
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Quick note: I believe that `\quad \quad` is the same as `\qquad`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `tabular`:

[image]

For an overview over available commands for horizontal spacing, take a look at: [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/134144)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

Inputs:

\begin{tabular}{@{\quad}>{\(}l<{\)} @{\enspace-\enspace} l }
 G = \langle{V,E}\rangle & a weighted graph \\
 v_ 0                    & the initial node to determine distances from
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```