# Multiple Horizontal lines on same line

Tags: formatting, line

Is it possible to do something like this in Latex?
[image]

Comment: Why – yes, of course. But a precise description  would be better.

Comment: I've successfully create 2 lines using \rule, but I can't figure out how to specify the amount of space between them.

Comment: @COOKIE: See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: @COOKIE -- welcome to TEX.SE -- one method is in the answer below -- have alook please

Comment: Use `\rule{1in}{0pt}` for example.  (Horizontal `\strut`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
I want them on the same row, side by side. 
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
\line(1,0){50}\\
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\line(1,0){250}\\
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT --for bold lines**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
I want them on the same row, side by side. 
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
\linethickness{2pt}\line(1,0){40}\\
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\linethickness{2pt}\line(1,0){250}\\
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second Method**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}


\setlength{\unitlength}{.4in}
\begin{picture}(7,5)(0,0)
    \linethickness{2pt}
    \put(0,0){\line(1,0){1}}
    \put(5,0){\line(1,0){10}}

\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you explain how to position the lines. I'm also getting underfull/overflow hbox warning

Comment: the answer was in the context of your one line question -- the warnings can be avoided by experimenting with the length of the line given within the second pair of braces -- if desired you can ask a more detailed new question -- in case the answer meets the requirement predicted in your question you may like to accept the answer

Comment: sorry, could I add on to my original question, to make the lines a specific distance apart?

Comment: a new question is desirable to attract a larger audience -- your present question has already been marked for closure

Answer (score 0):

This is, admitedly, more TeX than LaTeX, but:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\vrule width 1cm height 4pt depth -1pt\hspace*{4cm}\vrule width 6cm height 4pt depth -1pt\relax

% you can play with height and depth for the position with respect
% to the baseline and the thickness
See the baseline: \vrule width 1cm height 4pt depth -1pt\hspace*{2cm}p\vrule width 5cm height 4pt depth -1pt\relax

See the baseline: \vrule width 1cm height 1pt depth 1pt\hspace*{2cm}p\vrule width 5cm height 1pt depth 1pt\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]