# How to add some spaces progressively in a multiple line equation using align environment?

Tags: equations, align

Hope you are doing fine. Now, to get straight to the point: I have a multiple line equation inside an align environment. I have been trying, with no success, to accommodate each line inside the equation so that the final product can be an equation showing a slight inclination...

[image]

Minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
\gamma_i\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_k\ \tilde{M}_{jk} &= const_{\alpha}\,{\Big[}\gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_1\,m_{11} \,+\\ 
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_2\,m_{12} \\ 
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_3\,m_{13} \\
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_1\,m_{21} \\
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_2\,m_{22} \label{someequation}\\ 
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\,m_{23} \\ 
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_1\,m_{31} \\ 
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_2\,m_{32} \\ 
 & + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_3\,m_{33}{\Big]}. 
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I have tried with `\qquad`, shifting the `&` around, removing it, `\hspace`, `{}`, and many other options, with no success. Is there any chance this can be done with some elegancy (or not)?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: unrelated but `\mathrm{const}` and don't use `align` for single line equations, use `equation`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Ultimately, this question is asking how to insert horizontal space, which is a duplicate of [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: Thanks @Mico! for the greetings and David Carlisle for the ```\mathrm``` tip and the ```align``` issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% only in old latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\z[1]{\hspace{#1em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{someequation}
\gamma_i\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_k\ \tilde{M}_{jk} = \operatorname{const}_{\alpha}\Bigl[
\begin{aligned}[t]
 & \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_1\,m_{11} \\ 
 &\z1 + \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_2\,m_{12} \\ 
 &\z2 + \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_3\,m_{13} \\
 &\z3 + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_1\,m_{21} \\
 &\z4 + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_2\,m_{22} \\ 
 &\z5 + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\,m_{23} \\ 
 &\z6 + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_1\,m_{31} \\ 
 &\z7 + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_2\,m_{32} \\ 
 &\z8 + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_3\,m_{33} \smash{\Bigr]}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David !!! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: the thing of using ```\equation``` environment instead of ```align```, as I see, is that it sets the equation number in the first line, and not in the middle of the equation, rigth?. How can I fix that?. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{someequation}
\begin{aligned}
\gamma_i\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_k\ \widetilde{M}_{jk} = \mathrm{const}_{\alpha}\, 
 & \bigl[\gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_1\,m_{11} + {}\\ 
 & \mkern0mu  + \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_2\,m_{12} \\ 
 & \mkern2mu  + \gamma_1\gamma_1\gamma_3\,m_{13} \\
 & \mkern4mu  + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_1\,m_{21} \\
 & \mkern6mu  + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_2\,m_{22} \\ 
 & \mkern8mu  + \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\,m_{23} \\ 
 & \mkern10mu + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_1\,m_{31} \\ 
 & \mkern12mu + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_2\,m_{32} \\ 
 & \mkern14mu + \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_3\,m_{33} \bigr]. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mico This is also a solution!.