# Rearrange subfigures

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I have been trying to include 4 subfigures but none of the code I have tried has worked but one. I think it is due to usepackage interference but I don't know. Anyway I manage to get the following:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \subfloat[first image]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.3\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{6.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill     
  \subfloat[second image]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.3\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{6.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill 
 \subfloat[third image]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.3\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{6}
    \end{minipage}}
    \hfill  
  \subfloat[fourth image]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.3\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{6}
    \end{minipage}}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

It gives me the output in the figure below. [image]

My question is if I can rearrange these so I have two subfigures at the top and two subfigures at the bottom?

Comment: Did you already try to replace the `\hfill` between the second and third `\subfloat` with an empty line?

Comment: They are positioned  like letters (using the same code) you have `a \hfill b \hfill c \hfill d`  so at least one word space between each and fitting as many as possible on the line, you want `a\hfill b` blank line `c\hfill d` so two paragraphs with two in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

With an empty line between the second and thid `\subfloat` you can get two images per row. The `minipage` environments are not really needed, so I removed them. I also made sure all images are of the same size. This was different in your original code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the demo option in your real document.
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \subfloat[first image]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{6.png}}
  \hfill     
  \subfloat[second image]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{6.png}}
  
  \subfloat[third image]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{6}}
  \hfill  
  \subfloat[fourth image]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{6}}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot! Is there any smooth way of reducing the spacing between the images?

Comment: Depending on how large the space shoul be, you could replace `\hfill` wiht `\quad` or `\qquad` or any other [command for horizontal space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/134144). If you want the images to be horizontally centered on the page, make sure to add `\centeirng` to the beginning of the `figure` environment.