# What are the \hbox \hss \hskip commands?

Tags: layout

I discovered in a TeX document the following commands :

```
$$ u_n \hbox to 0pt{\hskip 3mm$/$\hss} \longrightarrow 0 $$
```

I don't uderstand what they do exactly and how exactly how to use them (all i can grasp here is that it allows to put some text on top of some other text).

Are `\hbox to 0pt` and `{\hskip 3mm$/$\hss}` somehow related ?
What does `\hbox to 0pt` exactly do (what can it be used for) and what about `{\hskip 3mm$/$\hss}` ?
Are they part of some sort of list of `\hsomething` commands installed by default if LaTeX ?

Comment: These are TeX commands and are documented in the TeXbook bu Knuth.   I would have used `\rlap{\hskip 3mm$/$}`.  Basically it overlaps whatever is to the right (`\longrightarrow)` and inserts a math / 3mm in.  See also `\mathrlap` from the mathtools package.

Comment: thanks i didn't know about this book and this new command ! it will be very useful !!

Comment: @lucie: In terms of `\hskip`s (or `h`orizontal `skip`s), consider reviewing [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353)

Comment: they are tex primitoves but they should not appear in a latex document. use the equivalent latex commands `\makebox` or at least the plain tex derived versions, `\rlap`

Comment: This seems to be a “poor person's” hack instead of `\centernot\longrightarrow` that requires `\usepackage{centernot}`.

Comment: As David Carlisle said, you shouldn't be using these unless you are using plain TeX and not LaTeX. There can be weird interactions between these low-level commands and the higher-level commands in LaTeX  (e.g. `\hspace` or `\makebox`) which mess up the document formatting in mysterious and unexpected ways.

Answer (score 12):

`\hbox to <len>{<stuff>}` sets `<stuff>` inside a `h`orizontal `box` of width `<len>`. If `<len>` is `0pt` (or less than the width of `<stuff>`, the contents starts to overlap with surrounding elements. `\hss` (`h`orizontal `s`tretch/`s`hrink) can be used to change the alignment within the horizontal box.

TeX introduced some shorthand for `\hbox to 0pt{<stuff with \hss>}` in the form of `\clap`, `\llap` and `\rlap`, while in LaTeX you can use the more familiar `\makebox[0pt][<align>]{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l @{\qquad} >{$\lvert$}c<{$\rvert$} }
  \verb|\hbox to 0pt{abc}|          & \hbox to 0pt{abc}          \\ % right overlap
  \verb|\hbox to 0pt{\hss abc\hss}| & \hbox to 0pt{\hss abc\hss} \\ % center overlap
  \verb|\hbox to 0pt{abc\hss}|      & \hbox to 0pt{abc\hss}      \\ % right overlap
  \verb|\hbox to 0pt{\hss abc}|     & \hbox to 0pt{\hss abc}     \\ % left overlap
  \verb|\clap{abc}|                 & \clap{abc}                 \\ % center overlap
  \verb|\llap{abc}|                 & \llap{abc}                 \\ % left overlap
  \verb|\rlap{abc}|                 & \rlap{abc}                 \\ % right overlap
  \verb|\makebox[0pt]{abc}|         & \makebox[0pt]{abc}         \\ % center overlap
  \verb|\makebox[0pt][c]{abc}|      & \makebox[0pt][c]{abc}      \\ % center overlap (equivalent to \makebox[0pt]{abc})
  \verb|\makebox[0pt][l]{abc}|      & \makebox[0pt][l]{abc}      \\ % right overlap
  \verb|\makebox[0pt][r]{abc}|      & \makebox[0pt][r]{abc}         % left overlap
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Technically, `\hss` is defined a "horizontal skip equivalent to
`\hskip 0cm plus 1fil minus 1fil`" which "absorbs any positive or negative
width of the argument." (taken from [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic)).

Comment: Such dedication waw !! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 4):

Just out of academic interest.

`\hbox to 0pt{...}`

makes a box with zero width. However, this would produce an overfull box unless there is infinitely shrinking glue inside it, which the author of that hack provides as `\hss`, which is equivalent to

```
\hskip 0pt plus 1fil minus 1fil
```

so there is enough shrinkability and the text in the box will stick to the right. The text is a slash moved to the right by 3mm.

The output seems correct, but it's just by chance and if used in inline math the placement of the slash might be off.

A slightly better code that produces a seemingly right symbol that doesn't suffer from the mentioned problem would be

```
$$ u_n \mathrel{\hbox to 0pt{\hskip 2mm$/$\hss}}\longrightarrow 0 $$
```

(assuming plain TeX, of course).

In LaTeX you can do much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

\[
u_n \centernot\longrightarrow 0
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: omg thank you so much for this !! :DD