# Tables doesn't have vertical line at the right of each

Tags: tables, overleaf

I have two tables, but I can't figure out why it doesn't have vertical line at the right of the table. Could you tell me, where I've made mistake?

First one:

```
    \newline
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 $\emph{p}$ & $\emph{q}$ & $([\emph{p} \wedge$ & $(\emph{p} \Rightarrow \emph{q]})$ & $\Rightarrow$ & $\emph{q}$ \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
 \hline
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
 \hline
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Second one:

```
    \newline
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 $\emph{p}$ & $\emph{q}$ & $\neg$ & $(\emph{p} \vee \emph{q})$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $(\neg\emph{p}$ & $\wedge$ & $\neg\emph{q})$ \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 \hline
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 \hline
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 \hline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: in the first table you specified a rule after the 6th column, but you only have 5 columns and in second table you have a rule after the 9th column but only 8 columns

Comment: Off-topic: what you like to achieve with $\emph{q}$? Correct is just `$q$ ... etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry, but I can't find that rule. I'm totally new to Latex. I've been using it for like 2 hours.

Comment: @Zarko thank's! I'll change it.

Comment: Following @DavidCarlisle's suggestion, that's often why it's contextually easier to use the `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` approach to defining your `tabular` column specification. In your first instance: `|| *{6}{c} ||` would help highlight there are 6 columns; your second instance: `|| *{9}{c} ||` would help highlight there are 9 columns.

Comment: you have 6 c `cccccc||` so if you have 6 columns the last one will get || but you only have 5 columns, delete one of the c

Comment: Thank you guys! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related to specifying too many columns and then not using them all. Your first table has a column specification with 6 `c`entered columns, while you only supply 5 values per row before terminating the row (with `\\`). That leaves the last column (which also holds the righthand `||`) out of the row and therefore no vertical rules on the right. The same principle holds for the second table. In general, you can use a `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` approach to defining `<num>` columns, each of which will have a `<col spec>` specification. For example, `*{5}{c}` would be equivalent to `c c c c c`, and `*{3}{| c p{2cm}}` would be equivalent to `| c p{2cm} | c p{2cm} | c p{2cm}`. It's sometimes easier to ensure the same number of columns in the specification and the table by using the abbreviated form.

Here's a slightly different approach to showing the content, using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). It shows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ c c c @{\,} c c c @{\,} c c c } 
   \toprule
   p & q & [ & p & \wedge & (p \Rightarrow q) & ] & \Rightarrow & q \\
   \midrule
   0 & 0 &   & 0 &   0    &         1         &   &       1     & 0 \\ 
   0 & 1 &   & 0 &   0    &         1         &   &       1     & 1 \\
   1 & 0 &   & 1 &   0    &         0         &   &       1     & 0 \\
   1 & 1 &   & 1 &   1    &         1         &   &       1     & 1 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{array}
\]


\[
  \begin{array}{ c c c @{} c c c @{\,} c c c @{\,} c } 
    \toprule
    p & q & \neg & (p \vee q) & \leftrightarrow & ( & \neg p & \wedge & \neg q & ) \\
    \midrule
    0 & 0 &   1  &      0     &        1        &   &    1   &   1    &    1   &   \\ 
    0 & 1 &   0  &      1     &        1        &   &    1   &   0    &    0   &   \\
    1 & 0 &   0  &      1     &        1        &   &    0   &   0    &    1   &   \\
    1 & 1 &   0  &      1     &        1        &   &    0   &   0    &    0   &   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `@{<stuff>}` in the column specification changes the space between the adjacent columns to `<stuff>`. So, in the above cases, I insert a small [horizontal space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) `\,` between the two columns.