# Quiz with answer (please recommend me a format of TeX document)

Tags: macros, counters, exercises

I want to make a quiz using TeX that "looks like"

> Problem 1) Let $f(x)=x^2$. Evaluate $f'(1)$.
>
> Problem 2) Let $A$ be a matrix such that
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ What is the value of $|A|$?
>
> Answer1) 2
>
> Answer2) 3

And I made a TeX file "written as"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\prob}{\par\bigskip\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{num}\textbf{Problem \arabic{num}) }}
\newcommand{\ans}{\par\bigskip\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{num}\textbf{Answer \arabic{num}) }}

\begin{document}
\prob
Let $f(x)=x^2$.
Evaluate $f'(1)$.
 
\prob
Let $A$ be a matrix such that
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
What is the value of $|A|$?

\setcounter{num}{0}

\ans
2
\ans
3
\end{document}
```

It prints the result pretty well, except for the fact that the problem statements and answers are separated.

I want to type answer 1 just after problem 1, which would prevent many kinds of errors.

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: @Mensch Hello. Sorry for an elementary question. But I need someone's help.

Comment: Look at the exercise package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise

Comment: @Mensch The document is so lengthy. I can use the package like `\begin{Exercise}` but the format isn't what I want. Surely, the document offers many customization, but I think there is a lighter way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the options `answerdelayed` of `exercise` package, you can write the answer near the problem in your code, but print them only when you like with `\shipoutAnswer`.

I think `exercise` is the simplest package for exercises, if you find its documentation lengthy, I don't know what you would say of TikZ one! :D

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Problem}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Answer}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)\ }

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
    Let $f(x)=x^2$.
    Evaluate $f'(1)$.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
    2
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}
    Let $A$ be a matrix such that
    \[A=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.\]
    What is the value of $|A|$?
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
    3
\end{Answer}
\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: if you prefer commands instead of environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Problem}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Answer}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)\ }

\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\begin{Exercise}#1\end{Exercise}}
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\begin{Answer}#1\end{Answer}}

\begin{document}
\prob{Let $f(x)=x^2$.
    Evaluate $f'(1)$.}
\ans{2}
\prob{Let $A$ be a matrix such that
    \[A=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.\]
    What is the value of $|A|$?}
\ans{3}
\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow.. So the answer is the `Exercise` package and its special option. It looks good except for the fact that you used environment, while 'command' (like `\exercise`) will be much simpler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @govindah You can create also your own commands, see my edit. But if the problem text is long, it is better to use environments (you can use environments for long texts and commands for short text in the same document, if you like).

Comment: Just a curiosity: but $$ is it necessary?

Comment: @Sebastiano I copied the OP's code, I think \[...\] should be better. I'll edit my answer, thank you.

Comment: @govindah Off-topic, please look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks for your additional method, using only method!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Plus, I originally prefer \( and \[ to $ and $$. But I thought that \( and \[ don't work in this webpage, that's why I used $ and $$. I'll use \( and \[ next time! Thanks for your comment! One more comment. I looked the `exercise` manual file onece more.  The expression 'lengthy' I used is not right I think. Like you said, it is simple compared to `tikz` or `enumitem`. This is because of my immatureness. But after using many years of TeX, I'm not that accustomed to the CTAN things, just my personal problem.

Comment: @govindah Don't worry, if you have problems don't hesitate to ask here!

Comment: Thanks for your hospitable comment. Actually I'm not native english user. Maybe that's (partially) why I'm having difficulty still in this good website(StackExchange) and CTAN. Thanks for your good alternative code, I got to use it on my own. But I have one more minor question. I understand what `\ExerciseName` and `\ExerciseHeaderNB` mean (they are so obvious). But what is the single backslash? i.e. `\noindent\ExerciseName"\" \ExerciseHeaderNB` Also, in `\noindent\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)\ ` You've used two backslashes. What do they mean?

Comment: Is it like, `\%` or `\#`? I mean, they visualize % and # literally. Is `\ `(backslash + indentation) making an indentation?

Comment: @govindah A backslash followed by a space simply adds a space.

Comment: @govindah see point 14. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing/74354