# Increase the space around \circ in script style

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Is there some way to increase the horizontal space around `\circ` when it is in script style? For example, the label over the arrows in a commutative diagram is often put in script style, and left almost no extra space around `\circ`:

[image]

This usually won't be a big problem, but in some cases the labels look quite ugly (for example, the vertical labels in the following diagram):

[image]

I wonder if there is some way to have the normal thin space around `\circ` as in text or display mode?

Below is a MWE to play with.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet & \bullet
    \arrow["a \circ a",from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\( a \circ a \)

\( \scriptstyle a \circ a \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try  `\arrow["a \; \circ \; a",from=1-1, to=1-2]`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/161015

Comment: In math mode you can always use "\" to add a small space between the symbols: 
$(123)$ or $(1\ 2\ 3)$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can coerce `tikz-cd` to apply this to all labels, but it works with the explicit command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\cdl}[1]{\text{$\medmuskip=0.6\medmuskip#1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\bullet \arrow[r,"\cdl{a\circ a}"] & \bullet \\
\bullet \arrow[r,"a\circ a"] & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I reduced `\medmuskip` because the standard value seems too large in this case.

Why does this work? Because `\text` appears in `\scriptstyle`, so it uses `\sf@size` inside it, but math is in text style.

I believe that in LuaTeX you can change the behavior that in script style no space around binary operation symbols is added.

Comment: That looks okay, but what about the (non-centered) `\circ` in the labels on the vertical arrows in the question?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That’s done with the same method