# How to write ~2.1 in LaTex?

Tags: tilde

When I type '~2.1' here, the distance between ~ and 2.1 is perfect (i.e. exactly what I want). How can it be achieved in LaTeX?

With `$\sim\,2.1$`, the distance between them is too large.

Comment: then do not use `\,`

Comment: @user187802, `\,` is supposed to give the smallest space in math mode.

Comment: No, the smallest space is the one without `\,`

Comment: @user187802, `$\sim2.1$`, `$\sim\!2.1$` and `$\sim\,2.1$` all produce the same thing here. Not sure why. Maybe that's because 'elsarticle' is being used as document class.

Comment: `$\sim 2.1$` ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\sim` acts like a relation and therefore is surrounded by a `\thickmuskip`, similar to what you'll find around `=`:

[image]

```
$a \sim b$

$a = b$
```

If you add `\showoutput` to your document, you'll find the spacing inserted in the `.log`:

```
....\mathon                                    <- $
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 a                         <- a
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771   <- \thickmuskip
....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 ^^X                       <- \sim
....\penalty 500                               <- ...penalty to limit line breaks
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771   <- \thickmuskip
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b                         <- b
....\mathoff                                   <- $
    ----------------------------------------
....\mathon                                    <- $
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 a                         <- a
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771   <- \thickmuskip
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 =                          <- =
....\penalty 500                               <- ...penalty to avoid line breaks
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771   <- \thickmuskip
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b                         <- b
....\mathoff                                   <- $
```

You can change the setting of `\sim` as a `rel`ation to be set as an `ord`inary math element using `{\sim}` or `\mathord{\sim}`, and then [add spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  \verb|\sim 2.1|: &
    $\sim 2.1$ \\
  \verb|\sim \, 2.1|: &
    $\sim \, 2.1$ \\
  \verb|{\sim} 2.1|: &
    ${\sim} 2.1$ \\
  \verb|\mathord{\sim} 2.1|: &
    $\mathord{\sim} 2.1$ \\
  \verb|{\sim} \, 2.1|: &
    ${\sim} \, 2.1$ \\
  \verb|\mathord{\sim} \, 2.1|: &
    $\mathord{\sim} \, 2.1$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
%>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$\sim\!2.1$

$\sim2.1$
%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{document}
```

[image: tilde]