# On Scaling Horizontal Spacing Commands

Tags: spacing, scaling, horizontal, horizontal-spacing

Many horizontal spacing commands are of course, found in [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing/74354#74354).

I would like to inquire if, say, invoking the `\enspace` command, which produces a space of .5em, if it is possible to (simply) produce a horizontal space of exactly .25em by doing something analogous to the way one would scale an `includegraphics` picture?

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent Adjust space.\\[10pt]
Adjust \enspace space.\\[10pt]
Adjust .5\enspace space.\\[10pt]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: Is there something simple, along the lines of `.5\enspace` (which as you can see---does not work) that will produce a horizontal space (in this case) of .25em? More generally, if such can also be applied to other spacing commands such as `\medspace` or `\quad`, etc.?

Thank you.

Comment: no, `\enspace` is `\kern0.5em`  just use `\hspace{.25em}`

Comment: Read the manual section 6.4.2 Spaces.

Comment: Depending on the font, the "em" and "en" might not actually be the expected values. TeX calculates one way, but the font does its own thing. If you actually want the specific width of a character (including its side bearings) you can put it in a box, measure the width of the box, but not actually use the box for print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, `\enspace` is `\kern0.5em` just use `\hspace{.25em}`

[image]

if you really want this you do not want to scale the command that adds the space, but you can see what space was added and scale *that*. This simple version discards any stretch component

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\def\hscale#1{{%
\ifnum\lastnodetype=11
\skip0=\lastskip\unskip
\hskip#1\skip0\relax
\else
\ifnum\lastnodetype=12
\dimen0=\lastkern\unkern
\kern#1\dimen0\relax
\fi
\fi}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent Adjust space.\\[10pt]
Adjust\enspace space.\\[10pt]
Adjust\enspace\hscale{.5} space.\\[10pt]
Adjust\enspace\hscale{5} space.\\[10pt]
Adjust\quad space.\\[10pt]
Adjust\quad\hscale{2.5} space.\\[10pt]
xxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this very helpful answer.