# Command for space

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The command `\space` produces a space in normal mode.
Is there an equivalent, explicit command in math-mode (which is not `$\ $`)?

Comment: There is `\hspace{}` and `\vspace{}`. Others also exist as well as used defined spaces.

Comment: it is not clear what you would want as an answer. `\space` works in math as in text and expands to  space token, but they do nothing in math. why not `\ ` ?

Comment: You might be interested in [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: Yes, it is `\space`. Well, you object, this does nothing in math mode. Indeed, it is what the rules say and, I add, there is very seldom need for a standard space in math mode. What's your use case?