# Placing two figures side by side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, subfloats, subcaption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side)
>   [Subfigures placed horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24127/subfigures-placed-horizontally)

I want to place two figures side by side in my document. I am using the `subcaption` package and my code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % if you want blackboard bold symbols e.g. for real numbers
\usepackage{graphicx} % if you want to include jpeg or pdf pictures
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{tworoundgameeffortvaryingmujnegative}
        \caption{J=-1}
        \label{fig:tworoundvarymujnegative}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{tworoundgameeffortvaryingmujpositive}
        \caption{$J=1$}
        \label{fig:tworoundvarymujpositive}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Effort levels in round one and two with varying $\mu$. $\alpha=1$, $v=0.25$ and $w=0.25$}
    \label{fig:effortlevelsvarymu}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For some reason my two pictures get put on top of each other. Does anybody know why this may be the case?

Comment: This is a very common problem; write`\end{subfigure}%` for the first subfigure. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/4427

Comment: you give `.5\textwidth` to each figure. Unfortunately this not always adds `1\textwidth`, due to rounding errors or other skips (for example newlines which are seen as spaces by tex). Better give some margin for error using `.49\textwidth`

Comment: @JLDiaz Rounding errors don't play role in this case, due to `\hfuzz`.

Comment: @Alex [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @JLDiaz No, it's definitely not a rounding error problem, but it is due to the space caused by the new line.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the speedy replies, problem solved from the first comment

Comment: @JLDiaz using `\end{subfigure}%` (note the ending `%`) allows one to use `.5\textwidth` :)